Azure DevOps Pipeline Error: Password Not an Integer in snowsql Command
I'm encountering an issue with my Azure DevOps pipeline where I'm trying to run a snowsql command with a password retrieved from Azure Key Vault. The pipeline retrieves the secret correctly, but when I use it in the snowsql command, I get an error stating that the password is not an integer.
Here is the relevant part of my pipeline script:
- script: |
    export PATH=$PATH:~/snowflake
    echo "Running Snowflake Initialization Scripts..."
    ~/snowflake/snowsql -a "$SNOWSQL_ACCOUNT" -u "$SNOWSQL_USER" -r "$SNOWSQL_ROLE" -w "$SNOWSQL_WAREHOUSE" -p "$(SnowflakePassword)" -f scripts/1_initialize_db.sql
  displayName: 'Run Snowflake Initialization Scripts'

Error message:
Running Snowflake Initialization Scripts...
<my snowflake secret password> is not a valid integer
Try "snowsql --help" for more information.

##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.

I am seeing the secret value in the error so I am getting it back. Just not sure how to update the script to not capture as an integer.
What I've tried:

Verified secret in Key Vault: the secret is correctly stored in Azure Key Vault.
Checked access policies: the service principal has Get and List permissions for the secret.
Used variable expansion: ensured that the variable is correctly expanded using curly braces.

Observations

When I use curly brackets for variable expansion, the password appears blank in the error message.
When I use the password with round brackets, it shows the actual password but results in the same error.

Additional information:

The password contains special characters.
I have verified the environment variable is set correctly by printing it before running the snowsql command.

Question
How can I correctly pass the password retrieved from Azure Key Vault to the snowsql command in my Azure DevOps pipeline without encountering the "not an integer" error?
Thank you for your help!

Is this a Linux or Windows agent?

It is a Linux agent.

Consider setting environment variables at the task level - it might help to avoid issues such as encoding, special characters, etc.
Instead of specifying the password in the command line:
- script: |
    export PATH=$PATH:~/snowflake
    echo "Running Snowflake Initialization Scripts..."

    ~/snowflake/snowsql ... -p "$(SnowflakePassword)" ...
  displayName: 'Run Snowflake Initialization Scripts'

Try using the SNOWSQL_PWD environment variable, as per Specifying passwords when connecting:
- script: |
    export PATH=$PATH:~/snowflake
    echo "Running Snowflake Initialization Scripts..."

    # snowsql command WITHOUT the -p option
    ~/snowflake/snowsql ...
  displayName: 'Run Snowflake Initialization Scripts'
  env:
    SNOWSQL_PWD: $(SnowflakePassword) # <----------------- set environment variable


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78428911/558486

still giving the below error:
*** is not a valid integer
Try "snowsql --help" for more information.```

Try echoing the environment variable into a file and then use cat to display its content, to ensure the password is correct.

Also try "${password}" instead of ${password} (if your password doesn't contain double quotes ")

The logs show
Password content from file:
***

*** is not a valid integer

Try "snowsql --help" for more information.


Thanks this worked. I will mark it as solved, but now I am running into an error where it says: Running Snowflake Initialization Scripts... 250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 2 attempt(s).Aborting If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help. Goodbye!

@DEicebergslim that's a different story :-)

-p is a parameter for the port number, not the password. The documentation explains how to use passwords with SnowSQL: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start#specifying-passwords-when-connecting

Ohhh how could I miss that in the documentation? -P (uppercase) is for the password,  -p (lowercase) is for the port number - that's why the error message was ... is not a valid integer.
